# Ipython and FreeBSD failed to compiled

Tags: python, compiler-errors, ipython, freebsd, sourceforge

I'm trying to install Ipython on my FreeBSD server (9.3) using ports.
But when I launched `make && make install clean` at the end, I have this error message:

> I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/docbook.xsl
>   warning: failed to load external entity "http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xocbook.xsl"
>   compilation error: file /tmp/xmlto-xsl.Nu8pKc line 4 element import
>   xsl:import : unable to load http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/ma
>   *** [zmq_bind.3] Error code 1
>   1 error
>   *** [all-recursive] Error code 1
>   1 error
>   ===> Compilation failed unexpectedly.
>   Try to set MAKE_JOBS_UNSAFE=yes and rebuild before reporting the failure to
>   the maintainer.
>   *** [do-build] Error code 1
>
> Stop in /usr/ports/net/libzmq4.
>   *** [install] Error code 1
>
> Stop in /usr/ports/net/libzmq4.
>   *** [lib-depends] Error code 1
>
> Stop in /usr/ports/net/py-pyzmq.
>   *** [run-depends] Error code 1
>
> Stop in /usr/ports/devel/ipython.
>   *** [stage] Error code 1

On SourceForge, I have a 404.

What can I do?

Best regards
AH

Comment: Try to set MAKE_JOBS_UNSAFE=yes and rebuild before reporting the failure to the maintainer.

Comment: Even when I do `make MAKE_JOBS_UNSAFE=yes install clean` I still have this error. 
`I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl
warning: failed to load external entity "http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl"
compilation error: file /tmp/xmlto-xsl.5qMBzu line 4 element import
xsl:import : unable to load http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl`

Comment: I also try with pip by using `pip install ipython[notebook]` but I have this answer : `pip : no match`

Comment: Do pip install "ipython[notebook]" - [ ] are special characters in some shell

Comment: Thank, in fact notebook was installed but I had an issue with `py-pyzmq` so I did a `pkg install py-pyzmg` and it works! Thank a lot. Best regards. AH